# Query treating large number as a string

Tags: 7, database

I am trying to run a select statement on a table for a column.
The column is decimal(20,0) unsigned.

A majority of the entries can be found using the select statement:

```
db_query('SELECT * FROM {foo_table} WHERE foo_id = :other_id',array(':other_id' => $value))
```

and $value is a string holding a large number, and example number is 395589699550470144

I believe that query is treating the $value as a string for some of the larger numbers. Now this query works.

```
db_query("SELECT * FROM {foo_table} WHERE foo_id = $value")
```

But this query is insecure due to user input method.

Is there a way to force the query to always convert the string to a number safely?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) What problem are you actually having? Is your first example not bringing back the correct results? Is your server running on 32 or 64 bit architecture?

Comment: The problem is that the first query doesn't work for all values, but the second does. The version of php is 5.3 and 32 bit, I have no control over the environment.